# How to mount Refinery based site to subdirectory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger, refinerycms, rails-engines

I'm trying to deploy a Refinery based site to a subdirectory on a domain using Apache and Phusion Passenger. Somehow it almost works, but not quite. Does anybody have any experience with this and can point me to what I'm missing?

**Here's what I've tried so far:**

At first I just made a symlink from the DocumentRoot of til site to the public directory of the app:

```
ln -s /webapps/myapp/public /www/myapp
```

And added the following to the apache virtual host section:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ...
    RackBaseURI /myapp
    <Directory /www/myapp>
       Options -MultiViews
    <Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Pointing a browser to the /myapp subdirectory on the server gives me the app, as expected. However, the various links generated in the backend (found under `/myapp/refinery`) as well as the menu entries in the frontend points to the root of the site. That is, if I click on the "Pages" tab it tries to forward me to `/refinery/pages` while the correct path would be `/myapp/refinery/pages`.

Thinking that Refinery is made as a Rails Engine, I figured I should need to mount it to the `/myapp`-directory, so I changed config/routes.rb like this:

```
mount Refinery::Core::Engine, :at => Rails.env.production? ? '/myapp' : '/'
```

However, this now moves the site to `/myapp/myapp` instead. The links now makes sense pointing to `/myapp/resource`, but since the resources have moved another level down I'm still stuck.

I already have both redmine and another custom rails 3.0 app running under subdirectories of the same site, with no problems. Somehow refinery seems confused, though, and I can't see what I'm missing.

Looking at the Rack docs I've even tried changing my config.ru like this:

```
map '/myapp' do
    require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment',  __FILE__)
    run MyApp::Application
end
```

But that confuses the system even more, and all I get back is:

```
Not Found: /refinery
```

When I try to get the `/myapp/refinery` page.